# YCM error. The ycmd server SHUT DOWN (restart wit...the instructions in the documentation

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

I installed YCM with vim plug, but I may have shut down before process finished. Now when I start vim I get this error "The ycmd server SHUT DOWN (restart wit...the instructions in the documentation."

I've googled but can not find workable solution. I don't see anything in the documentation that helps. But I am new to vim and coding in general so may be missing something.

:YcmDebugInfo comes back with "Server errored, no debug info from server".

I have tried :YcmRestartServer, but to no result -- it pauses then returns the same error. I have also run :PlugInstall and :PlugUpdate, and all plug ins, including YCM, are coming back as up to date.

Comment: it would be greatly helpful if you also give the log or debug info along with OS and other environment details.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I ran into the same issue with Vundle and fixed it like this:
After installing cmake, I cd'd into ~.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe and ran 
        `python install.py`

Comment: I couldn't run it but after I installed python-devel packages then it works fine thanks.

Comment: This fails on vim 8.2. Cmake seems to be expecting an olde r Python version and exits with an error.

Answer (score 13):

I was also facing the same problem with vim and I am using vim-plug plugin manager. To overcome this I did this:

```
cd ~/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme
python3 install.py
```

Done !!!

Comment: I use Vundle so for me it was `cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe`

Answer (score 12):

Another problem that may cause that error is conda, you should run `install.py` from the python's system and not the conda one, to do that use

```
/usr/bin/python ./install.py
```

from the youcompleteme folder inside vim

Comment: Quite similarly `pyenv` introduce shims which when invoking the `python` binary rely on static Python library instead of dynamic ones.  Solution is to use the system Python with `/usr/bin/python` as suggested by Mike in his answer.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me in 2023 -- had the same issue with Anaconda.

Answer (score 8):

I was also facing the same issue but I have solved by executing the following commands in the Ubuntu terminal

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/
sudo pip install cmake
python install.py
```

or

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/
sudo pip3 install cmake
python3 install.py
```

Comment: Thanks. I used your code with one modification:```sudo pip3 install cmake```.

In most system, pip3 is used along with python3.

Comment: thanks for your update. when i have used at that time pip was working but now in new systems comes with pip3 as default. thanks for your comment

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I have solved
Mac OS Catalina 10.15.3 
python 3.7
vim 8.2

Install ycm with 'Vim-plug' using Plug 'ycm-core/YouCompleteMe'

1. cd ~/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe
2. brew install cmake
3. python ./install.py

Answer (score 2):

2023:

- macOS Monterey
- Anaconda
- Python installed with homebrew

Had to :

```bash
cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/
# DONT use conda python in the following install step
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3 ./install.py
```

Comment: I was in the same situation. this helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cd ~/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme
$ bash install.sh
(or)
$ python3 install.py
```

It will only work if you have installed the python3.7 version

Comment: you may add some explanation that how this code is the answer of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did this recently with following environments

**Mac OS Mojave 10.14.3**

Vim 8.1.300

Python 3.7

Java version 1.8.0_40

```
$vim --version | grep python
+comments          +libcall           -python            +viminfo
+conceal           +linebreak         +python3           +vreplace
```

Installed `ycm` with `Vundle` using `Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'` and then running `:PluginInstall`

The plugins in downloaded to `~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe`

```
$cd  ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
$python3 installer.py --java-completer
```

This creates appropriate files under `/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/eclipse.jdt.ls` (make sure these and inner directories **are not** owned by root unless you always work as a root)

now open vim and execute `:YcmRestartServer`

You should be good to go.

Try `:YcmDebugInfo` to check if everything is fine

```
Printing YouCompleteMe debug information...
-- Client logfile: /var/folders/t4/y8zpydv91sv2dszlb1_3qw_r0000gn/T/ycm_1xgp1ub9.log
-- Server Python interpreter: /usr/local/bin/python
-- Server Python version: 3.7.0
-- Server has Clang support compiled in: False
-- Clang version: None
-- Extra configuration file found but not loaded
-- Extra configuration path: ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/.ycm_extra_conf.py
-- Server running at: http://127.0.0.1:58050
-- Server process ID: 2334
-- Server logfiles:
--   /var/folders/t4/y8zpydv91sv2dszlb1_3qw_r0000gn/T/ycmd_58050_stdout_wzk9oksu.log
--   /var/folders/t4/y8zpydv91sv2dszlb1_3qw_r0000gn/T/ycmd_58050_stderr_xjb7zjn2.log
```

**CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)**

Vim 8.1.1362

Python 3.7.3

Java openjdk version "1.8.0_191"

Overall process remains same, but I had couple of difficulties on Centos

- Vim was not compiled with Python support

```
sudo vi /etc/ld.so.conf
```

added `/usr/local/lib` to it which had `libpython3.7m.so.1.0` file

```
sudo ldconfig
git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
cd vim
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ --enable-python3interp=yes --with-python3-command=/usr/local/bin/python --with-python3-config-dir=
```

Rest of the procedure remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue and fixed it today. Here's what I've done

- Install YCM's requirement in `vundle`

  `cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe; python3 install.py`
- Reproduce the problem, then check its log in `vi` mode. The error I had reads

  `Traceback (most recent call last): File ImportAndCheckCore ycm_core = Import Core() File /.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycmd/utils.py", line 493, in ImportCore import ycm_core as ycm_core ImportError: ~/miniconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found`
- Check whether `libstdc++.so.6` contains `GLIBCXX_3.4.30`, but receive `GLIBCXX_3.4.2x` which apparently doesn't satisfy the dependency

  ```
  strings ~/miniconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_3.4.30
  GLIBCXX_3.4.2x
  ```
- Then seek the correct `libstdc++.so.6` that contains the expected `GLIBCXX_3.4.30`

  ```
  sudo find /usr -type f -name "libstdc++.so.6*"
  /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.30

  strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.30 | grep GLIBCXX_3.4.30
  GLIBCXX_3.4.30
  ```
- Copy `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.30` and create a softlink to `~/miniconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6`

---

> Edited on 20230606

On `6.1.31-1-MANJARO`, the same problem got fixed after running `cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe; python3 install.py`