# Vim plugin youcompleteme: cannot start Ycm Server / YcmToggleLogs shows nothin

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, youcompleteme

I am quite new to Vim on Mac OSX 10.13. I installed a few plugins, especially for use with Python.

Thus I installed YouCompleteMe & compiled it. Originally I got an error because a trial of Kite shut the server down. But this I deactivated and now I restart and restart the server just to get it shutdown.
And the YcmToggleLogs does not show anything :-(

I followed all of the advice given here: [YCM error. The ycmd server SHUT DOWN (restart wit...the instructions in the documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47667119/ycm-error-the-ycmd-server-shut-down-restart-wit-the-instructions-in-the-docu)

But still it doesn't work.

And of course I followed along with the official install manual:

> Install YCM plugin via Vundle
> Install cmake, macvim and python
>
> Note that the system vim is not supported.
>
> brew install cmake macvim python
> .
> Install mono, go, node and npm
>
> brew install mono go nodejs
>
> Compile YCM
> cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe python3 install.py --all

Btw, when compiling everything I get several warning along these lines:

> ld: warning: text-based stub file /*****/CoreFoundation.tbd and library file
> /****//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation are out of sync.
> Falling back to library file for linking.

Any ideas what I can do to get it off the ground?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, with VIM >8.1

To solve the issue, run the installer from the plugin. 
Go to vim folder

```
cd ~/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe
```

and run the installer.sh

```
./installer.sh
```

hope this solution solves your as well.

Comment: .vim/plugged because I have Plug installer. With Vundle, the path should be ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe